# Como ler quebra de linha em arquivo em C?

Tags: c

Olá! Minha dúvida é a seguinte, há um arquivo em que eu possuo o seguinte conteúdo: `\nteste\n`, porém quando eu faço a leitura do mesmo com o seguinte código:

```
int main(){
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    char buffer[20];

    fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);

    printf("%s", buffer);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Não há quebra de linha e é exibido exatamente o conteúdo do arquivo (`\nteste\n`), considera \n como sendo a barra e a letra n separados. Há alguma forma de fazer ele "interpretar" a quebra de linha?
Agradeço!

Comment: O seu arquivo não contém quebra de linha, e sim o literal "\n". Por que?

Comment: Porque eu desejo usar o arquivo para alimentar variáveis, cada linha sendo uma variável, entende? E elas tem conteúdo e tamanho diferentes umas das outras, se eu usar a quebra de linha literal no arquivo esse método se torna inviável

Comment: Em C é a função fgets() que lê um arquivo linha a linha. fscanf() é para fazer parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não existe nenhuma função na biblioteca padrão capaz de interpretar strings literais para a sua sequencia de escape equivalente.

Uma alternativa seria implementar uma função capaz de fazer isso, veja só:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void converter( char * saida, const char * entrada )
{
    int estado = 0;
    *saida = '\0';

    while(*entrada)
    {
        if(!estado)
        {
            if(*entrada == '\\')
                estado = 1;
            else
                strncat(saida, entrada, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            switch(*entrada)
            {
                case 'a'  : strcat(saida, "\a"); break;
                case 'b'  : strcat(saida, "\b"); break;
                case 'n'  : strcat(saida, "\n"); break;
                case 't'  : strcat(saida, "\t"); break;
                case 'r'  : strcat(saida, "\r"); break;
                case 'f'  : strcat(saida, "\f"); break;
                case '\"' : strcat(saida, "\""); break;
                case '\'' : strcat(saida, "\'"); break;
                case '\\' : strcat(saida, "\\"); break;
                default: break;
            }
            estado = 0;
        }
        entrada++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    char buffer[100];
    char bufaux[100];

    fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);
    converter(bufaux, buffer);

    printf("%s", bufaux);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Por exemplo, se o conteúdo do seu arquivo for algo como:

```
foo\nbar\nbaz\n
```

A saída seria:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/IndelibleTechnicalTests)

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Primeiramente, obrigado a todos que se dispuseram a ajudar, e desculpe a demora para responder o tópico. Eu consegui uma solução perfeita para meu caso, considerando o código do Lacobus.
Arquivo de texto (exemplo):

```
 Digite os dados abaixo para criar sua conta.\n
```

O código então percorre a frase inteira, e a barra "\" é substituída por um espaço em branco, e o "n" é substituido pelo caractere 10 (quebra de linha), algo assim:

```
for(i = 0;i<array_size;i++) {
        // 92 = \, 110 = n, 32 = space, 10 = \n
        for(j = 0;j<strlen(gameTextContent[i]);j++) {
            if(gameTextContent[i][j] == 92 && gameTextContent[i][j+1] == 110) {
                gameTextContent[i][j] = 32;
                gameTextContent[i][j+1] = 10;
            }
        }
}
```

Caso esteja um pouco estranho a primeira vista, eu estou usando um array multidimensional:

```
gameTextContent[array_size][content_size]
```